# Error in using "vaadin file upload"(polymer) via nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, polymer, vaadin

I am trying to upload a simple file using the vaadin file upload element(refer https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-upload)

I am using nodejs and express with multer as middle-ware on the server side.

The nodejs simplified code is as follows:

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});
```

I tried with an HTML element in my index.html and this code works

```
<form id        =  "uploadForm"
     enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
     action    =  "/api/photo"
     method    =  "post"
>
<input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

But I want to use the vaadin upload element. I wrote the code

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-upload/vaadin-upload.html">

<vaadin-upload id="userPhoto" target="/api/photo"></vaadin-upload>
```

When I use this, it does not work as expected. I am able to see the vaadin element. But I am unable to upload a file. As I select the file, the server responds with the string 'Error uploading file'. I am pretty new to polymerjs and web development. Could someone please point me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your backend code, you have to change the file parameter name from `'userPhoto'` to `'file'`.

In case of the native HTML form, it sends a file in the parameter declared by the `name` attribute of the `<input type="file">`.

When using the Vaadin Upload element, the files are sent in the same manner as by the HTML form. But instead of the provided `name`, they are sent in the parameter called `"file"`.

Note that you have the `id="userPhoto"` attribute for the upload. The `id` is a different attribute, that does not act like a `name`.

Unfortunately, the file parameter name for the upload requests cannot be easily customized for now. We are planning to add more upload request customization features in future.